# Max IOPS for non-EBS-optimized EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to set up a database server using an m3.large EC2 instance, and would like to use a provisioned IOPS EBS backing store to maximize performance. Purchasing an EBS-Optimized instance would be ideal, but the instance size required to get this feature is out of the budget for this project.

Has anyone experimented with or observed a rough max IOPS you can get on a provisioned IOPS non-optimized store? If I set it too high, I am paying for provisioned bandwidth that the machine could never possibly leverage over its connection, and if I set it too low, I am unnecessarily choking my instances access to its data. I was considering provisioning 500IOPS, but I don't have any evidence to back this number other than guessing based off the IOPS count used in examples for EBS-optimized instances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EBS averages 100 IOPS but can "burst to hundreds" per https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/details/. The ability to burst indicates that the network bandwidth (used by EC2) is *potentially* there for 500 PIOPS to be used, depending on the other EC2 instances on the same host.

Your latency is going to vary more than with an EBS-Optimized instance. PIOPS on EBS-Optimized instances work by having dedicated network bandwidth straight to the EBS servers. On a non-optimized instance, other network traffic from your instance or your instance's neighbors can affect the EBS traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Looking at that link, I guess what I am asking about is the statement "When attached to EBS-optimized instances, Provisioned IOPS volumes can achieve single digit millisecond latencies and are designed to deliver within 10% of the provisioned IOPS performance 99.9% of the time." does not provide contrast against the latency and %-of-provisioned IOPS delivered on non-EBS-optimized PIOPS volumes.

Comment: Your latency is going to vary more than with an EBS-Optimized instance. PIOPS on EBS-Optimized instances work by having dedicated network bandwidth straight to the EBS servers. On a non-optimized instance, other network traffic from your instance or your instance's neighbors can affect the EBS traffic.